# Недопонимание с памятью

Tags: c, указатели, память

Я создаю функцию, единственным аргументом которой будет указатель на int **. В теле функции я создаю автоматическую переменную и инициализирую ее неким значением. Затем своему указателю присваиваю адрес данной переменной. Код выглядит примерно так:

```
void function(int ** p){

    int count = 5;
    *p = &count;

}
```

В main() я создаю указатель на int * и для него вызываю данную функцию, тобишь:

```
int main(){

    int * p = NULL;
    function(&p);

    printf("MAIN = %d\n\n", *p); /* выводит 5 */

   return 0;
}
```

И у меня возникает вопрос - почему не уничтожаются данные в памяти переменной count после того, как поток выходит из функции? Неужели данные в памяти у любого класса хранения живут на протяжении выполнения всей программы?

Comment: это UB, в данном случае просто повезло и данные не успел кто-либо перезаписать... где-то здесь уже должно было обсуждаться с полноценным ответом.

Comment: Когда-то, давным-давно, умный человек сказал мне: "не жмакай на две звёздочки до тех пор, пока не разобрался с одной".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Потому что в си программист сам следит за памятью. Автоматически ничего не инициализируется и ничего не затирается. Неинициализированная или неправильно инициализированная переменная содержит мусор. Любой мусор.

Помимо этого, если программист не уследил за указателями или инициализацией, возникает так называемое *неопределённое поведение,* при котором программа может вести себя непредсказуемым образом.

Comment: Как это "ничего" не инициализируется автоматически? Статические данные, например, инициализируются нулями неявно.

Comment: @alexolut, да, про статические согласен.